# Why is my Git repository so large?

Tags: git, github

I'm current maintaining a project github, and it is ~ 200 commits.  I recently did a fresh fork / clone of the repo in a VM, and I was suprised to see the project directory on my local computer being 168MB (o.O)  When I download the master branch of the project using the download link on the github page for the project, and uncompress the zip it takes up a staggering 4.4MB of space of my local computer.  Could someone please explain to me in layman's terms why the fork / clone is taking up 168MB of space and master branch is only taking up 4.4MB of space?

FYI, I believe I never uploaded any large files to the repo, so I don't think it is a large file problem.

Comment: The project directory contains the files in their latest version, but also all the history of all the files in all the branches. And it's probably not optimized for space, but for speed. What you should measure instead of the size it takes on your disk is the download size when checkouting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that your clone has your git history in the `.git` directory. Take a look at the size of the .git directory (if on linux or the like `cd $GIT_DIR; du -hs .git`).

You could attempt to clean up the .git directory.

```
git fsck --full
git gc --prune=today --aggressive
git repack
```

This may save you some space. But in general, this is most likely your local branches and history saved in the `.git` directory in your repo.